# How we can solve heat equation with this particular boundary conditions (error NDsolve)?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematica-online, heat-equation

Please I need help to solve this heat equation with this particular boundary conditions:
This the Code I tried in Mathematica:

```
(*Numerical solution*)
homogene = {D[g[x, t], {t, 1}] - D[g[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0};
(*Initial conditions*)
ice = {g[x, 0] == x*(1 - x)};
(*Dynamic boundary conditions*)
bce = {D[g[0, t], {t, 1}] - D[g[0, t], {x, 1}] == 0, 
   D[g[1, t], {t, 1}] + D[g[1, t], {x, 1}] == 0};
(*solution*)
sol11 = (NDSolve[{homogene, ice, bce}, g, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.1])
```

As a result, I get this error: `NDSolve::bdord: Boundary condition (g^(0,1))[0,t] should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation.`

Comment: You have first order in time PDE, but you are supplying bc which contains derivative w.r.t  time.  You can't do that.  The order of BC/IC should be lower than the order in the PDE.  `D[g[0, t], {t, 1}]` This is like with normal ODE. If you have first order ODE to solve, then initial conditions can't be first order derivative.

Comment: @Nasser You make it clear for me, thank you. Is there is any other method we can apply to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

We can use method of lines to solve this problem as follows

```
np = 40;
ugrid = 1/np Range[0, np];



fd1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ugrid]; fd2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], ugrid]; m1 = 
 fd1["DifferentiationMatrix"]; m2 = 
 fd2["DifferentiationMatrix"]; vart = 
 Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; uxx = m2 . vart; ux = 
 m1 . vart; var = Table[u[i], {i, Length[ugrid]}];
u0[x_] := x (1 - x);
eqns = Join[{D[u[1][t], t] == First[ux], 
    D[u[np + 1][t], t] == -Last[ux]}, 
   Table[D[u[i][t], t] == uxx[[i]], {i, 2, np}]];
ics = Table[u[i][0] == u0[ugrid[[i]]], {i, Length[ugrid]}];

tmax = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, var, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

Visualization

```
lst = Flatten[
   Table[{t, ugrid[[i]], u[i][t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 1, .01}, {i, 1, 
     Length[ugrid]}], 1];
ListPlot3D[lst, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "g"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Figure 1]